# Jssor Slider Adjust Speed After Initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

Im using Jssor Slider but I need to adjust the speed ($SlideDuration) during some events, Is possible to do that? How?

Comment: You'd adjust speed before initialization.

Comment: So, the answer is: is not possible to do that??

Comment: I meant I need to adjust the speed during slider is running...

Comment: You can customize jssor slider as the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I created this method inside the jssor.slider.js.

> ```
>    function NewSpeed(speed){
>        _SlideDuration = speed;
>    }
>
>    _SelfSlider.$NewSpeed = NewSpeed;
> ```

Then I can use it as follow:

> instance.$NewSpeed(integer);